# Segfault for omp parallel loop

Tags: segmentation-fault, openmp

I have 2d array of floats and I want to sort the indices of each row. I use a function for sorting. I am looping over the rows of an array and call sort function for each row. I just want this function call to be executed in parallel. The serial version works fine. But when I use omp parallel for, I get segfault. I have tried privatizing variables and making few loops critical, I am still not able to understand the origin of this error. Any help would be really appreciated.

Below is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
void QuickSort(float A[], size_t I[], size_t lo, size_t hi)
{
   while (lo < hi)
   {
      float pivot = A[I[lo + (hi - lo) / 2]];
      size_t t;
      size_t i = lo - 1;
      size_t j = hi + 1;
      while (1)
      {
         while (A[I[++i]] < pivot);
         while (A[I[--j]] > pivot);
         if (i >= j)
            break;
         t = I[i];
         I[i] = I[j];
         I[j] = t;
      }
    /* avoid stack overflow */
      if((j - lo) < (hi - j)){
         QuickSort(A, I, lo, j);
         lo = j+1;
      } else {
         QuickSort(A, I, j + 1, hi);
         hi = j;
      }
   }
}
//Declare number of data points
#define COUNT (10)             

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int  i,j;
   //Index array for every row
   size_t I[COUNT] ;
   //Array to keep first 5 sorted indices for every row
   size_t I_sorted[COUNT][5];
   //Array to fill random values, and random float variable        
   float fr, A[COUNT][COUNT], B[COUNT] ;
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   //Fill random float 2d array  of COUNT*COUNT dimentions
   for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {         // array of indexes
      for(j=0; j<COUNT ;j++){
         fr =  (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
         A[i][j] = fr;
         printf("%f\t",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
   }

   //Need to call QuickSort count number of times in parallel
   #pragma omp parallel for private(j)
   for(i=0 ;i<COUNT; i++) {
   //#pragma omp critical
   //Assign a row of A to B to pass for sorting, also make index array
      for(j=0 ;j<COUNT; j++) {
         B[j] = A[i][j];
         I[j] = j;
      }
      //Sort row indices
      QuickSort(B, I, 0, COUNT-1);
      //#pragma omp critical
      //Store sorted indices
         for(j=0;j<4; j++) {
            I_sorted[i][j] = I[j];
            //printf("%d\t",I_sorted[i][j]);
         }
      //printf("\n");
    }

    //Verify sorted array is correct
    printf("------------------------\n");
    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          printf("%d\t",I_sorted[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }

    return(0);
    }
```

The serial code works fine but compiling with fopenmp gives segfault.

Comment: Let's consider the case of two threads. The `for(i=0; i<COUNT; i++)` loop will be split into two parts: one thread will do i in range 0...COUNT/2 and other for i in COUNT/2+1 ... COUNT range.  Both thread will execute in the same time, and you must have no any shared memory region to be written to from both threads without synchronization. Your code has shared array B modified by both threads which is incorrect. Try to use local array (define it inside the `{ ... }` block of parallel for loop) and check other variables for access from both threads.

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply. I am bit confused, do you mean I need to make array B private? If so how can I declare whole array to be private in a loop? I dont not want to make those inner loop parallel, I have tried making that section by adding omp critical still I get the error.

Comment: @osgx Hey, I do understand the problem now. I moved both B and I array inside the loop and everything works fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the case of two threads. The `for(i=0; i<COUNT; i++)` loop will be split into two parts: one thread will work for `i` values in range `0`...`COUNT/2` and the second will work for `i` values in `COUNT/2+1`...`COUNT` range. Both thread will execute in the same time, and you must have no any shared memory region to be written to from both threads without synchronization. (If they do write to the same address, this will be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition and it makes program unpredictable.)

Your code has array `B` which is shared in and modified by both threads. This simultaneous access is incorrect. Try to use local array (define it inside the `{ ... }` block of parallel for loop, [some docs](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-data.html)) and check other variables for write access from both threads.